# TensorFlow bazel building error: C++ compilation of rule '@boringssl//:crypto' failed

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel, boringssl

I'm using a supercluster which only uses glibc 2.12. I managed to install Bazel(version 0.15.0) successfully, but failed to bazel build tensorflow with a long error log, a part of which is:

> > ERROR: /home2/yangto/.cache/bazel/_bazel_yangto/b9c3b9594c932d1e804df44467c1c0d2/external/boringssl/BUILD:115:1: C++ compilation of rule '@boringssl//:crypto' failed (Exit 1)
> >     external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/rsaz-avx2.S: Assembler messages:
> >     external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/rsaz-avx2.S:37: Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'vpxor'
> >
> > external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/rsaz-avx2.S:80: Error: no such instruction: 'vpbroadcastq .Land_mask(%rip),%ymm15'
> >
> > external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/rsaz-avx2.S:91: Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'vpaddq'
> >
> > external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/rsaz-avx2.S:92: Error: no such instruction: 'vpbroadcastq 0-128(%rsi),%ymm10'
> >
> > external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/rsaz-avx2.S:93: Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'vpaddq'
> >
> > .... .etc

And when using --verbose_failures to monitor the failure, I obtained the following message:

```
/home2/my_name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_name/b9c3b9594c932d1e804df44467c1c0d2/external/boringssl/BUILD:115:1: 
C++ compilation of rule '@boringssl//:crypto' failed (Exit 1): 
gcc failed: error executing command 

cd  /home2/my_name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_my_name/b9c3b9594c932d1e804df44467c1c0d2/execroot/org_tensorflow && \

exec env - \

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/public/gnu/gcc/4.8.4/lib:
      /usr/public/gnu/gcc/4.8.4/lib64:
      /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:
      /usr/public/torque/lib \

PATH=/home2/my_name/bazel/output:
    /home2/my_name/anaconda3/bin:
    /usr/public/gnu/gcc/4.8.4/bin:
    /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:
    /usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release:
    /usr/public/torque/bin:
    /usr/public/torque/sbin:
    /usr/public/moab/bin:
    /usr/public/moab/sbin:
    /usr/local/sbin:
    /usr/sbin:
    /sbin:
    /home2/my_name/bin:
    /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:
    /usr/local/bin:
    /bin:
    /usr/bin:
    /opt/ganglia/bin:   
    /opt/ganglia/sbin:
    /usr/java/latest/bin:
    /opt/rocks/bin \

PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/home2/my_name/anaconda3/bin/python \
PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/home2/my_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages \
TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \

/usr/public/gnu/gcc/4.8.4/bin/gcc 
-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE 
-fstack-protector 
-Wall 
-B/usr/public/gnu/gcc/4.8.4/bin 
-B/usr/bin 
-Wunused-but-set-parameter 
-Wno-free-nonheap-object 
-fno-omit-frame-pointer 
-g0 -O2 
'-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' 
-DNDEBUG 
-ffunction-sections 
-fdata-sections 
-MD -MF 

bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/boringssl/_objs/crypto/external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/p256-x86_64-asm.pic.d 
-fPIC 
-iquote external/boringssl 
-iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/external/boringssl 
-iquote external/bazel_tools 
-iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools 
-isystem external/boringssl/src/include 
-isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/external/boringssl/src/include 
-isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/boringssl/src/include 

'-march=native' 
-DGPR_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_MODE 
-Wa,--noexecstack 
'-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700' 
-Wall 
-Werror 
'-Wformat=2' 
-Wsign-compare 
-Wmissing-field-initializers 
-Wwrite-strings 
-Wshadow 
-fno-common 
'-std=c11' 
-Wmissing-prototypes 
-Wold-style-definition 
-Wstrict-prototypes 
-fno-canonical-system-headers 
-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined 
'-D__DATE__="redacted"' 
'-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' 
'-D__TIME__="redacted"' 

-c external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/p256-x86_64-asm.S 
-o bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/boringssl/_objs/crypto/external/boringssl/linux-x86_64/crypto/fipsmodule/p256-x86_64-asm.pic.o
```

Can anyone help me with this? (I've looked through online for similar problems but still struggling).

---

**Additionally Note:**
I'm using shared supercluster without sudo permission. Wondering if there would be any solutions in my case...

Comment: This looks relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/431

Comment: Hi @Jin, I've seen suggestions using Docker. However, I'm using a supercluster without root permission, so I cannot install Docker by myself, which is not installed on the cluster for some unknown reason... Is there any more suggestions?